# Finding the volume of a shape

Tags: integration, analysis

You're given the following:

$z=x^2-y^2$

$z=0$

$x=3$

You need to find the volume of the shape which is formed with these equations.
So, z=0 is the x y plane, x=3 is 3 for every z value. The upper bound for the z integral should be the hyperbolic paraboloid, the lower bound should be 0, x should be bounded with higher bound 3 and lower bound 0, now y is where I didn't know what to do any more. Can anyone give me a tip about it? I know that in the end, I have to integrate.

Also, what's the perfect way to graph 3D objects? Do you take the z to be a constant and then sketch it or...?

Comment: try polar coordinates

Comment: the traditional method to plot stuff like this is to recognize that the first equation is a conic section, and use your knowledge of those to make the plot.

but, wolfram alpha makes knowing conic sections pointless: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+z+%3D+x%5E2+-+y%5E2&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to set $z$ to be a constant and then graph the curves. I took some values and in Desmos.com made the following picture:
[image]

We see that indeed, the planes $z=0$ and $x=3$ do cut out a finite portion of the surface (the picture can be thought of as "looking down" from the $z$-axis).

The picture should help you with deciding the integration limits for the triple integral. You could, for example, calculate the area that $z=x^2 - y^2 =\text{constant}$ makes with the line $x=3$.